How to link external image in Flask
I am designing a website using Flask. Currently, I am trying to render a about us webpage using render_template. I have a manage.py in classified ads/back end/manage.py. The about.html sits in classified ads/front end/templates/about.html. The logo image is in classified ads/front end/assets/image/logo.png. The logo is supposed to be at the header and it links to homepage. However, when running flask --app manage run --debug, the browser does not show the logo. It gives a 404 for the logo image not found error in console.
//manage.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="../front end/templates")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app.run(debug=True)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>MyListing16 - About us</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header-top">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="/front end"
            ><img src="/front end/assets/image/logo.png" alt=""
          /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <h3>about</h3>
  </body>
</html>

![logo](https://i.sstatic.net/f5KkPzP6.png)

![about.html](https://i.sstatic.net/8aFNrJTK.png)

![file path](https://i.sstatic.net/26fKXRLM.png)

I changed the img src attributes from relative path ../assets/image/logo.png to full path /front end/assets/image/logo.png. Still, the logo does not show up.

Why are you using spaces in your folder names? Use underscores or dashes instead please

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Put image in front end/static folder, no assest ( front end/static/logo.png ) (If it doesn't works please share your python code)

I have renamed the assets to static, and placed the image folder inside it. I also use url_for to find the logo.png and I get rid of the white space in folder names. It worked!

Can you vote up for it please :)

already did, but not enough points.

oh can you mark my answer as "accepted" please
